# GCP Pubsub Bigquery Subscriptions - can't create due to missing permissions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-pubsub

I get an error (in red, in picture below) whilst creating pubsub Bigquery subscription. Error shows up in subscription creation view:

[image]

First question - why is this error appears in the first place?

One of my attempts to solve this was to try to first create standard subscription, then add these missing permissions by assigning a role using such command:
`gcloud pubsub subscriptions add-iam-policy-binding EventIngestSubscription-4475d78 --member=serviceAccount:service-388032002134@gcp-sa-pubsub.iam.gserviceaccount.com --role="roles/roles/bigquery.dataEditor"`, but this produces `ERROR: (gcloud.pubsub.subscriptions.add-iam-policy-binding) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Role roles/bigquery.dataEditor is not supported for this resource.` error.

When I tried to set `pubsub.subscriber` roles instead of `bigquery.admin` - it worked.

Thanks a lot on any insights and suggestions on how to create a Bigquery Subscription. Am really stuck with this one...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The permission that needs to be set is not on the subscription, it is on the BigQuery table itself. Therefore, you are not going to be able to set the BigQuery permissions on the subscription. Instead, you need to ensure that the service account has `roles/bigquery.dataEditor` on the table you are using with the subscription. You can do this with the `bq` command-line tool:

```
bq add-iam-policy-binding --member="serviceAccount:service-<project number>@gcp-sa-pubsub.iam.gserviceaccount.com" --role=roles/bigquery.dataEditor -t "<dataset>.<table>"
```

This permission is needed so that Pub/Sub can write to BigQuery on your behalf.

Comment: Thanks @Kamal Aboul-Hosn, that helped!
Why is that pub-sub serviceAccount not listed with other service accounts when I run `gcloud iam service-accounts list` ? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Providing more context here, specifically to @ironstone13's comment related to not being able to locate the service account in the error message.

From [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/create-bigquery-subscription):

"Pub/Sub creates and maintains a service account for each project in the format service-project-number@gcp-sa-pubsub.iam.gserviceaccount.com."

To remedy this, we can give the service account the proper access via the GUI:

1. In the Google Cloud console, go to the IAM page.
2. Go to IAM
3. Click Grant access.
4. In the Add Principals section, enter the name of your Pub/Sub service account. The format of the service account is service-project-number@gcp-sa-pubsub.iam.gserviceaccount.com. For example, for a project with project-number=112233445566, the service account is of the format service-112233445566@gcp-sa-pubsub.iam.gserviceaccount.com.
   n the Google Cloud console, go to the IAM page.
5. In the Assign Roles section, click Add another role.
6. In the Select a role drop-down, enter BigQuery, and select the BigQuery Data Editor role.
7. Click Save.