# Google Cloud Pub/Sub: Service account does not exist

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-iam

I've been following the steps in the Google tutorial, [Using Pub/Sub with Cloud Run tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/pubsub).

All ok until allowing Google's service account to create auth tokens ([Integrating with Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/pubsub#integrating-pubsub) 2.b.)

Here I run the command:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding PROJECT_ID \
   --member=serviceAccount:service-PROJECT_NUMBER@gcp-sa-pubsub.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
   --role=roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator
```

PROJECT_ID and PROJECT_NUMBER are replaced by their actual values of course.

However I get the error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.projects.add-iam-policy-binding) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Service account service-PROJECT_NUMBER@gcp-sa-pubsub.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not exist.
```

(I've replaced my actual project number by PROJECT_NUMBER here for privacy, believe me I've double-checked that it's the correct ID and number.)

There's a note in this guide about IAM changes taking several minutes to propagate but I'm seeing the same error hours after the previous command completed successfully.

I've also tried adding this through the Cloud Console IAM UI but I get a consistent error:
[using IAM UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VslpV.png).

I'm already using Pub/Sub in this project and it's still working with a Pull subscription.

### Update

I've finished setting this up in another project following the same instructions and that's working fine, so I'm certain this isn't a misunderstanding of the tutorial, there's something wrong with this project (or rather, the Google-managed service account for this project).

Comment: Have you tried doing these steps here https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/pubsub#integrating-pubsub?

Comment: service-<PROJECT_NUMBER>@gcp-sa-pubsub.iam.gserviceaccount.com is a Google-managed service account. The error message is telling you the service account does not exist. Did you enable the Pub/Sub service? Use the command `gcloud services list` to list enabled services. The command `gcloud services enable pubsub.googleapis.com` will enable Pub/Sub. Also, verify that you have billing enabled and there is no billing issue.

Comment: I can confirm that the pub/sub appears in `gcloud services list`, in fact I'm already using it in this project for a pull queue and that's been working fine. There's no billing issue.

Comment: I've finished setting this up in another project following the same instructions and that's working fine, so I'm certain this isn't a misunderstanding of the tutorial, there's something wrong with this project (or rather, the Google-managed service account for this project).

Answer (score 7):

I was able to force the account to be created with the command ([docs](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/services/identity/create)):

```
gcloud beta services identity create --project PROJECT_ID --service pubsub
```

After this the `add-iam-policy-binding` command completed without error.

Comment: Great thanks, I think this should be accepeted as the answer. It saved me hours of life

Comment: don't work for me, i folow this post and worked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73732801/gcp-pubsub-bigquery-subscriptions-cant-create-due-to-missing-permissions